# About android Sensor TYPE_GYROSCOPE

Tags: android, rotation, sensors, gyroscope

Hello friends in my app `I want to put sensor like when I rotate mobile from north to south at this time sensor is called, for that I see TYPE_GYROSCOPE is used but I don't know exactly how it can be used for my app`

Please give any example for when I rotate my phone from north to south that sensor type is called. I have used the following

```
  @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                 if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
         // code here
    }
    }
```

but if is not true always so not get pointer to the inside if body

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the [How to use Gyroscope Sensor in Android](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/01/how-to-use-gyroscope-api-and-remain.html)

Also check out the [Here](http://www.touchqode.com/misc/20101025_jsug/20101025_touchqode_sensors.pdf) for all the sensors detail.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answers, For this of movement Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE is not used instead i used Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER it usefull to found x and y co-ordinate as mobile change its orientation like movement or north to south. now this working weell for my apps.